# ExtJS 4 - Printing Forms Programatically sometimes gives "Print Preview Failed" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Good day. I am developing a Web Application and there's a part where I print the form on button click. To achieve this, I overrode the definition of my Form Panel so that I can call `form.print()` anywhere in my code when I need to. Here is how I overrode my form:

```
Ext.define('my_app_name.override.form.Panel', {
    override: 'Ext.form.Panel', 

    print: function(pnl) {
        if (!pnl) {
            pnl = this;
        }

        // instantiate hidden iframe
        var iFrameId = "printerFrame";
        var printFrame = Ext.get(iFrameId);

        if (printFrame === null) {
            printFrame = Ext.getBody().appendChild({
                id: iFrameId,
                tag: 'iframe',
                cls: 'x-hidden',
                style: {
                    display: "none"
                }
            });
        }

        var cw = printFrame.dom.contentWindow;

        // instantiate application stylesheets in the hidden iframe
        var stylesheets = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
            stylesheets += Ext.String.format('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{0}" />', document.styleSheets[i].href);
        }

        // various style overrides
        stylesheets += ''.concat(
            "<style>", 
            ".x-panel-body {overflow: visible !important;}",
            // experimental - page break after embedded panels
            // .x-panel {page-break-after: always; margin-top: 10px}",
            "</style>"
        );

        // get the contents of the panel and remove hardcoded overflow properties
        var markup = pnl.getEl().dom.innerHTML;
        while (markup.indexOf('overflow: auto;') >= 0) {
            markup = markup.replace('overflow: auto;', '');
        }

        var str = Ext.String.format('<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>',stylesheets,markup);

        // output to the iframe
        cw.document.open();
        cw.document.write(str);
        cw.document.close();

        // remove style attrib that has hardcoded height property
        cw.document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].removeAttribute('style');

        // print the iframe
        cw.print();

        // destroy the iframe
        Ext.fly(iFrameId).destroy();
    }
});
```

Then on a click of a button in my Web App, I do something like:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('formIDHere');
form.print();
```

However, this code is rather inconsistent at times. There are times that I can print the form no problem and there are times that it gives the "Print Preview Error" message. I can't replicate the issue consistently and the logs aren't showing anything so I'm in the dark.

What I've noticed however, is that when I save my project (I'm using Sencha Architect), preview it (or refresh the current window where I'm previewing my Web App), stay with the web app all throughout the process (meaning I don't shift tabs or windows), hit the print button, the print preview appears and I don't have problems with it.

So far I haven't tested in other Web Browsers. Any ideas anyone? I'll be really thankful for anyone who can point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to update this. Thanks to whoever upvoted my question.

The concept is simple. Since ExtJS4 is asynchronous, I placed my code in "blocks" and then I delayed my calls to those functions to ensure that they finish constructing what they need to construct before moving on to the next part.

```
print: function(pnl) {

    if (!pnl) {
        pnl = this;
    }

    // instantiate hidden iframe

    var iFrameId = "printerFrame";
    var printFrame = Ext.get(iFrameId);

    if (printFrame === null) {
        printFrame = Ext.getBody().appendChild({
            id: iFrameId,
            tag: 'iframe',
            cls: 'x-hidden',
            style: {
                display: "none"
            }
        });
    }

    var cw = printFrame.dom.contentWindow;
    var stylesheets = "";
    var markup;
    // instantiate application stylesheets in the hidden iframe



    var printTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
        // print the iframe
        cw.print();

        // destroy the iframe
        Ext.fly(iFrameId).destroy();

    });


    var strTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
        var str = Ext.String.format('<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>',stylesheets,markup);


        // output to the iframe
        cw.document.open();
        cw.document.write(str);
        cw.document.close();

        // remove style attrib that has hardcoded height property
        //             cw.document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0].removeAttribute('style');
        printTask.delay(500);

    });

    var markUpTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
        // get the contents of the panel and remove hardcoded overflow properties
        markup = pnl.getEl().dom.innerHTML;
        while (markup.indexOf('overflow: auto;') >= 0) {
            markup = markup.replace('overflow: auto;', '');
        }
        while (markup.indexOf('background: rgb(255, 192, 203) !important;') >= 0) {
            markup = markup.replace('background: rgb(255, 192, 203) !important;', 'background: pink !important;');
        }

        strTask.delay(500);
    });


    var styleSheetConcatTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){

        // various style overrides
        stylesheets += ''.concat(
            "<style>", 
            ".x-panel-body {overflow: visible !important;}",
            // experimental - page break after embedded panels
            // .x-panel {page-break-after: always; margin-top: 10px}",
            "</style>"
        );

        markUpTask.delay(500);
    });


    var styleSheetCreateTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){


        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
            stylesheets += Ext.String.format('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{0}" />', document.styleSheets[i].href);
        }
        styleSheetConcatTask.delay(500);
    });

    styleSheetCreateTask.delay(500);
}
```